# What is deduped in npm packages list?

Tags: node.js, npm

I am running command as npm list and I get below mentioned list as my dependencies and I want to know what is the meaning of **deduped**. Please let me know the meaning of this.

[image: Please check below mention image...!!!!]

Comment: This should help https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/dedupe

Answer (score 179, accepted):

`deduped` is short for "deduplicated" (duplicates were removed).
The documentation for [`npm dedupe`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/dedupe) explains how `npm` does this:

> Searches the local package tree and attempts to simplify the overall structure by moving dependencies further up the tree, where they can be more effectively shared by multiple dependent packages.

In other words, it looks if multiple packages have the same dependencies (meaning the same packages **and** version range) and "points" them to the same package.

The same package is referenced, so it doesn't have to be installed twice.

Also, it moves the packages "up the tree" (flattens the tree). This makes total sense as otherwise one package would have to look in the `node_modules` of some other package (which would be kind of messy) and helps to simplify the dependencies.

You can validate this, as every package in your dependency graph that says `deduped`, can be found at least one more time in the graph, usually at a higher level.

In the screenshot you posted `content-type@1.0.4` is a dependency of `body-parser`. A bit further down, it's also listed as a direct dependency of express one level higher.

Answer (score 11):

With **npm v8.3** you can also use **overrides** for packages in your tree:

https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/configuring-npm/package-json#overrides

###### Why do I mention it?

-> overrides are also tagged with "deduped" no matter how high they are on the tree, so even if package x in branch y is only listed once it still will be marked "deduped"