# NPM: How packages are de-duped?

Tags: node.js, npm

How does de-duping work? Does NPM de-dupe packages with exact versions or different patch (~) and minor (^) versions?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52781142/what-is-deduped-in-npm-packages-list

Comment: That question is about what is de-duping. Mine is different.