# node docker image upgrade ini package to 2.0

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, node-modules

I using `node:lts-alpine` docker image. I want to upgrade `ini` package from `1.3.5` to `2.0.0`.

when I use  `npm install ini@latest -g` command, it still keeping the older version of `ini` package also?

```
 # npm list -g |grep 'ini@'
+-- ini@2.0.0
  | +-- ini@1.3.5 deduped
  +-- ini@1.3.5
  | +-- ini@1.3.5 deduped
  | | `-- ini@1.3.5 deduped
  | | | `-- ini@1.3.5 deduped
  | |   | | +-- ini@1.3.5 deduped
/ #
```

How to upgrade all the `ini` pckage version to latest in the docker image?

Thanks
SR

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is deduped in npm packages list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52781142/what-is-deduped-in-npm-packages-list)

Comment: @atline  if you see 3rd line, its not `deduped` one. I want to upgrade this package also `2.0.0` version

Comment: Did you find a solution to this sfgroups? I'm trying to close vulnerabilites in my docker image by upgrading the ini package but the older ini version is still there after scanning.

Comment: @toerq sorry I didn't find the fix for this issue.