# npm install is not choosing transitive dependency with the highest version number

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I'm working on a node project that involves an SDK and then a parent project consuming the SDK. In Java, maven or gradle will pick transitive dependency with the highest version number but how does that work in npm?

From the screenshot below, the SDK imports `debug` package with version `4.3.4` which is what I want to see in the parent project. However, npm picked the version `2.6.9` instead. I have tried defining the library version from `dependencies` or `overrides` section from SDK, none of them works.

I know that I can add an overide from parent project to force the newer version but am I doing something wrong that causes this or overriding dependency from parent project is the only way to resolve this? Is there something I can do in the SDK to enforce this library version from the consuming parent projects?

[image]

Base on the package-lock.json file, I looked into the actual `debug` package json file under the node_modules folder and confirmed that it is at version `2.6.9`

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Downgrade the node (npm) version to the required stable version and use `npm update` in terminal of visual Studio code.

Comment: Thanks! The `npm update` actually helps and updated version of the library from the parent project. I just looked at [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12478679/npm-install-vs-update-whats-the-difference) about the differences between the two and it makes more sense now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> In Java, maven or gradle will pick transitive dependency with the highest version number but how does that work in npm?

That is indeed one of the big differences between npm and Maven/gradle, regarding management of dependencies:

- Java handles only a *single* version of any given package per project. Therefore Maven and gradle have to choose a single common version of each dependency, even for transitive dependencies, which can possibly break their intermediate parent (start of the so called *dependencies hell*)
- Node module resolution is *per package*: each module can have its *own* `node_modules` folder, containing its own dependencies and specific version. It can still share dependencies though: Node walks up the folder tree until it finds a `node_modules` containing the dependency; this way it factorizes compatible versions.

  - Furthermore, as of npm@8.3.0, the [`overrides`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/configuring-npm/package-json#overrides) field enables forcing a different version of such transitive dependencies

This is what you see in your case:

- `body-parser@1.20.1` requires the [exact `debug@2.6.9` version](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser/blob/1.20.1/package.json#L14)
- `sailpoint-oss/sp-connector-sdk-js@1.0.0` specifies an [override of `debug@^4.3.4`](https://github.com/sailpoint-oss/sp-connector-sdk-js/blob/1.0.0/package.json#L53)
- *even though* `npm ls debug` and `package-lock.json` show the initial transitive version of 2.6.9, you can see that it says "[deduped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52781142/what-is-deduped-in-npm-packages-list)": it was actually *not installed*, and another version higher up the tree is used instead: 4.3.4 in your case.

Therefore if you inspect your actual folder structure, there should be no debug@2.6.9, only 4.3.4

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I just looked into the folder under node_modules but unfortunately, the package.json file from the debug module shows the version as `2.6.9`

Comment: Which version of npm was used to install the dependencies?

Comment: `npm -v` gives me `8.11.0`