# How to handle duplicated packages in built react application?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, hadoop-yarn

Currently I have a react components library that has `mapbox-gl@^2.8.2` as a dependency.

```json
"dependencies": {
    "mapbox-gl": "^2.8.2",
}
```

I'm consuming this components library in a web application built using react and vite, that web application also has `mapbox-gl@2.14.1` as dependency:

```json
"dependencies": {
    "mapbox-gl": "2.14.1",
}
```

When I am building the application, the final bundle has two versions of the package what increases bundle size a lot. There is anyway of making them to consume the same mapbox without compiling two mapbox since they are using the same major (without breaking changes)?

I already tried using peerDependencies but the final bundle size keeps the same, I think peerDependcies isn't the right tool for it.

**Resolution**: Adding the following code to the package.json of the web application made the components library start using the parent's mapbox version:

```
"resolutions": {
    "mapbox-gl": "2.14.1",
}
```

Looks like if you're using npm, instead of `resolutions` use `overrides`.

Comment: Use `Yarn or NPM Dedupe` : Running yarn dedupe or npm dedupe can help resolve duplicate dependencies

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is deduped in npm packages list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52781142/what-is-deduped-in-npm-packages-list)